# Using LoginRequiredMixin with async views?

Tags: django-views, python-asyncio, python-social-auth

I'm using Python 3.7, Django 3.1.7, social-auth-app-django 3.1.0.

I've just started playing with async views.  I can't get them to play nice with LoginRequiredMixin.  I've got this trivial view:

```
class TestView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        view = super().as_view(**initkwargs)
        view._is_coroutine = asyncio.coroutines._is_coroutine
        return view

    async def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'spi/test.jinja', {})
```

When I run this test:

```
class TestViewTest(ViewTestCase):
    def test_get(self):
        client = Client()
        response = client.get('/spi/test')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

It fails with an awe-inspiring stack dump (below), the gist of which is:

```
TypeError: object HttpResponseRedirect can't be used in 'await' expression
```

which I assume is due to the OAuth flow being run.  If I leave out the LoginRequiredMixin, the test passes.

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 147, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/python-distros/Python-3.7.3-install/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/python-distros/Python-3.7.3-install/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 212, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object HttpResponseRedirect can't be used in 'await' expression

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/python-distros/Python-3.7.3-install/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 630, in emit
    s = self.makePickle(record)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/python-distros/Python-3.7.3-install/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 602, in makePickle
    s = pickle.dumps(d, 1)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/python-distros/Python-3.7.3-install/lib/python3.7/copyreg.py", line 65, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError("can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__)
TypeError: can't pickle BytesIO objects
Call stack:
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/src/manage.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/src/manage.py", line 21, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 53, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 699, in run_tests
    result = self.run_suite(suite)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 641, in run_suite
    return runner.run(suite)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/python-distros/Python-3.7.3-install/lib/python3.7/unittest/runner.py", line 176, in run
    test(result)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/python-distros/Python-3.7.3-install/lib/python3.7/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/python-distros/Python-3.7.3-install/lib/python3.7/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 243, in __call__
    self._setup_and_call(result)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 279, in _setup_and_call
    super().__call__(result)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/python-distros/Python-3.7.3-install/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py", line 663, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/python-distros/Python-3.7.3-install/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py", line 615, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/src/spi/test_views.py", line 231, in test_get
    response = client.get('/spi/test')
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 739, in get
    response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 395, in get
    **extra,
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 470, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 711, in request
    response = self.handler(environ)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 142, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 130, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 114, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/middleware.py", line 52, in __call__
    return self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 114, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 114, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 114, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 114, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 114, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 114, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 114, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 114, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/src/tools_app/middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/src/tools_app/middleware.py", line 11, in __call__
    return self.get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 108, in response_for_exception
    exc_info=sys.exc_info(),
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 230, in log_response
    exc_info=exc_info,
Message: '%s: %s'
Arguments: ('Internal Server Error', '/spi/test')
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_get (spi.test_views.TestViewTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/src/spi/test_views.py", line 231, in test_get
    response = client.get('/spi/test')
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 739, in get
    response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 395, in get
    **extra,
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 470, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 716, in request
    self.check_exception(response)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 577, in check_exception
    raise exc_value
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 147, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/python-distros/Python-3.7.3-install/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/python-distros/Python-3.7.3-install/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/mnt/nfs/labstore-secondary-tools-project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 212, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object HttpResponseRedirect can't be used in 'await' expression

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.274s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out the problem is simply that LoginRequiredMixin isn't async-capable yet.  The work around is to implement the gist of LoginRequiredMixin in my view code.  The [supplied implementation of LoginRequiredMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/876dc0c1a7dbf569782eb64f62f339c1daeb75e0/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py#L66) is complicated, but most of it is dealing with the general case.  Stripping it down to the essential part that fits my use case, I ended up with:

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login

class TestView(View):
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        view = super().as_view(**initkwargs)
        view._is_coroutine = asyncio.coroutines._is_coroutine
    return view


    async def get(self, request):
        if not await sync_to_async(lambda: request.user.is_authenticated)():
            return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path())
        return render(request, 'spi/test.jinja', {})
```